# c# get rectangle bounds from image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

lets say i have a image [image]

i would like to find the black rectangle bounds(right,left,width,height) in the image(lets say there's no other black pixels in this image).
my code so far is:

```
    private unsafe Bitmap GetDiffBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
        {


            bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;


            int stride = bmData.Stride;


            int nWidth = bmp.Width;
            int nHeight = bmp.Height;

            for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)

            {
                //define the pointers inside the first loop for parallelizing
                byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
                p += y * stride;



                for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
                {
                    //always get the complete pixel when differences are found

                    if(p[0]==0 && p[1]==0 && p[2]==0)
                    { 
                           // p[0] = 255;
                           // p[1] = 255;
                           // p[2] =255;

                            right = nWidth;//geting the position of the lastest black pixel;

                      }  



                    p += 4;


                }

            }



            bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);


            return bmp;
        }
```

its seems like my nwidth is also as the image width-so its not working.. i got acces to these pixels and i can change them but i dont know why i can count them and find a proper bounds of the black rectangle... if anyone could help me i would really apperciate it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with this kind of image analysis:

1 replace

```
if(p[0]==0 && p[1]==0 && p[2]==0)
{
    right = nWidth;//geting the position of the lastest black pixel;
}
```

with

```
if(p[0]==0 && p[1]==0 && p[2]==0)
{ 
    right = x; //geting the position of the lastest black pixel;
}
```

Your x-iteration variable already counts which pixel you are on.

2 The code you provided only works for 32bpp pixel formats. If this is on purpose you should check if the bitmap you are analysing is in a compatible format.

3 With most compressed image formats you often won't get an exactly 0 on all 3 color channels for black, you should do a "less than something dark" check instead of a zero.

Comment: yeah.. a silly mistake.. had to use the `x` instead of `nWidth`... tnx.

Comment: and what did you mean check  instead of zero? @Sors

Comment: qitapi accepting the answer would be nice :) i meant that often you have "black" RGB values like (2,1,3) instead of (0,0,0) so you should check if the color values each less than your threshold instead of checking for 0